# Edit panel not showing up (Gear -> Edit Panel -> NOTHING??)

Tags: panels

If I go to a custom panel and click the gear, then click edit panel, the link changes as if a popup appeared, but nothing else shows up. I cleared my cache on my browser, computer, on the website, and even tried it on my coworker's computer but it still doesn't work. I also tried it on Chrome, Firefox, and Safari and still no success.  Any thoughts?

Comment: can you open console in the browser? maybe you have error in JavaScript

Comment: **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined**

and      

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'close' of undefined**

those are the two js errors I'm getting

Comment: try to fix these errors and the your panel will work

Answer (score 0):

You or one of the modules you installed is loading latest version of jQuery.  In the latest version of jQuery code like

```
if (jQuery.browser.msie && parseInt(jQuery.browser.version, 10) < 8) {}
```

does not work.

This code is in one of the Drupal core files. You can find it in modules/overlay/overlay-parent.js file on line 932, 975 and 985.

I do not recommend editing this file, but you can test this change on your localhost to make sure it is the latest version of jQuery which is causing this issue.

Comment: So are you recommending that I update jQuery?

Comment: I am recommending to make sure your site is loading default version of jQuery not the updated or latest version. In older version of jQuery drupal code works.